# django - how do i access the child's Meta from the parent?

Tags: django

I have the following forms, and I wish to know the child's `Meta.model` attribute from the parent. How do I do that?

```
class Profile_form(forms.ModelForm):

    @property
    def user_type(self):
        #access child meta here

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Form_A(Profile_form):
    class Meta:
        model = Some_model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `self._meta` for accessing `Meta` class for `self`.